# Get class properties by class name as string in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

Can I get class properties if i have class name as string?  My entities are in class library project and I tried different methods to get type and get assembly but i am unable to get the class instance.

```
var obj = (object)"User";
var type = obj.GetType();
System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);

object oform;
var clsName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("[namespace].[formname]");

Type type = Type.GetType("BOEntities.User");
Object user = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

nothing is working

Comment: Just to be sure, the `User` type is not in an assembly you already reference? Because then you should simply use `var type = typeof(User);` as your first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("User");
Object user = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Note:

- This will only look in `mscorlib` and the currently executing assembly unless you also specify the assembly in the name
- It needs to be a namespace-qualified name, e.g. `MyProject.User`

EDIT: To access a type in a *different* assembly, you can either use an assembly-qualified type name, or just use `Assembly.GetType`, e.g.

```
Assembly libraryAssembly = typeof(SomeKnownTypeInLibrary).Assembly;
Type type = libraryAssembly.GetType("LibraryNamespace.User");
Object user = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

(Note that I haven't addressed getting *properties* as nothing else in your question talked about that. But `Type.GetProperties` should work fine.)

Comment: this is not working me i have mentioned my class is in different project how can i get the reference of that assembly?

Comment: @ImranRashid: You mentioned that it was in a class library project, but you didn't say where *this code* was running. That's why it's important to be clear. Will edit.

Comment: Type.GetType("BOEntities.User") is returning null.  I am running it in  Unit Test project

Comment: @ImranRashid: Did you read my edit? And if you know the name at compile-time, why don't you just use `typeof`?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I get class properties if i have class name as string?

Of course:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
```

This will get a list of public instance properties. If you need to access private or static properties you might need to indicate that:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Assembly with namespace");
```